# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject leaves properties null

Tags: c#, json.net

TLDR: If all the fields of the deserialized object stay null, without any exceptions, check if your base class has the [DataContract] attribute, which makes Json.net ignore every property without [DataMember].

Sorry for the amount of code but I couldn't narrow down what causes the problem.

I have this json object with an array of the class AssetViewModel

```
[{
    "id":117,
    "name":"BMP",
    "creator":null,
    "extension":".bmp",
    "creationDate":"2019-03-31T23:18:20.8080488Z",
    "modificationDate":"2019-03-31T23:18:21.3191844Z",
    "size":1440056,
    "isDeleted":false,
    "version":0,
    "hasSinglePreview":true,
    "hasCollagePreview":false,
    "customPreviews":0,
    "group":null,
    "collection":null,
    "project":null,
    "tags":[]
}]
```

AssetViewModel:

```
public class AssetViewModel : IAsset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IUser Creator { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public bool HasSinglePreview { get; set; }
    public bool HasCollagePreview { get; set; }
    public int CustomPreviews { get; set; }
    public IGroup Group { get; set; }
    public ICollection Collection { get; set; }
    public IProject Project { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ITag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

If I deserialize it with, see below, it works fine.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AssetViewModel>>(content);
```

But with class AssetViewModel2 it doesn't:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AssetViewModel2>>(content);

public class AssetViewModel2 : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private CollectionViewModel _collection;
    private DateTime _creationDate;
    private UserViewModel _creator;
    private int _customPreviews;
    private string _extension;
    private GroupViewModel _group;
    private bool _hasCollagePreview;
    private bool _hasSinglePreview;
    private int _id;
    private bool _isDeleted;
    private DateTime _modificationDate;
    private string _name;
    private ProjectViewModel _project;
    private long _size;
    private BindableCollection<TagViewModel> _tags = new BindableCollection<TagViewModel>();
    private int _version;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            if (_id == value) return;
            _id = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) return;
            _name = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public UserViewModel Creator
    {
        get => _creator;
        set
        {
            if (_creator == value) return;
            _creator = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public string Extension
    {
        get => _extension;
        set
        {
            if (_extension == value) return;
            _extension = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get => _creationDate;
        set
        {
            if (_creationDate == value) return;
            _creationDate = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public DateTime ModificationDate
    {
        get => _modificationDate;
        set
        {
            if (_modificationDate == value) return;
            _modificationDate = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public long Size
    {
        get => _size;
        set
        {
            if (_size == value) return;
            _size = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public bool IsDeleted
    {
        get => _isDeleted;
        set
        {
            if (_isDeleted == value) return;
            _isDeleted = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public int Version
    {
        get => _version;
        set
        {
            if (_version == value) return;
            _version = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public bool HasSinglePreview
    {
        get => _hasSinglePreview;
        set
        {
            if (_hasSinglePreview == value) return;
            _hasSinglePreview = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public bool HasCollagePreview
    {
        get => _hasCollagePreview;
        set
        {
            if (_hasCollagePreview == value) return;
            _hasCollagePreview = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public GroupViewModel Group
    {
        get => _group;
        set
        {
            if (_group == value) return;
            _group = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public CollectionViewModel Collection
    {
        get => _collection;
        set
        {
            if (_collection == value) return;
            _collection = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public ProjectViewModel Project
    {
        get => _project;
        set
        {
            if (_project == value) return;
            _project = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public BindableCollection<TagViewModel> Tags
    {
        get => _tags;
        set
        {
            if (_tags == value) return;
            _tags = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    public int CustomPreviews
    {
        get => _customPreviews;
        set
        {
            if (_customPreviews == value) return;
            _customPreviews = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
}
```

The properties are the same, except in this class they have backing fields with NotifyOfPropertyChange() for WPF binding. I changed some of them to concrete types because I thought this might cause some trouble, but it didn't help.

All the properties for result stay null if deserialized with AssetViewModel2 and I don't get any exceptions.

What am I doing wrong in AssetViewModel2?

Comment: If you change `AssetViewModel2` to only have properties with simple types in it (`DateTime`, `string`, `int` etc) does it then populate this properties correctly?

Comment: No breakpoints in properties of AssetViewModel2 are not hit.

Comment: And yes even with only simple types it doesn't insert the values.
But i guess the main problem is that the breakpoints in the properties setters aren't hit.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dYhtex works fine for me - suggesting that there is either something weird in your base class, or the extra properties (that I deleted) aren't being handled property. Add the properties I deleted, one by one, until you find the culprit.

Comment: @mjwills the something weird in your base class, pointed me into the right direction. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the base class. I am using caliburn micros PropertyChangedBase. The class has a [DataContract] attribute, which makes it necessary to add the [DataMember] attribute to properties, which should be de/serialized.

Solutions:

- Copy the class without the [DataContract] attribute and add [JsonIgnore] to IsNotifying or
- add the [DataMember] attribute to every property, that should be de/serialized.